# Combine two Select statements in one call

Tags: oracle

I am trying to query a table to find first the exact match to a column,
in case the match fails; select the closest one in the range.

For e.g.

testTable

```
  id        width       cost

  1         10.2        100
  2         10.5        200
  3         10.1         50  

 Select * from testTable where width = 10.3;
```

in case this returns without record I want to go for the nearest one in the range of 10.1 to 10.9.

EDIT1: it's Oracle; updated the tag

Comment: Is this a MySQL or Oracle DB question? Please tag carefully.

Comment: What if more than one row is "closest"? "The nearest **one**" means it's unique; but even if the `width` column does not have duplicates, in your example 10.5 and 10.1 are equally "near" to 10.3. Do you want to select them both?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most databases you can do something like this:

```
Select *
from testTable
order by abs(width - 10.3)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Some databases might use `limit`, `top`, or even `where rownum = 1`, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You would write something like this:

```
 select * from (
    Select * from testTable where width = 10.3
    union
    Select * from testTable where width > 10.1 and width < 10.9
    order by abs (10.3 - width) asc
) T LIMIT 1
```

And yes, it can be reduced to what [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44788877/8113019) showed

```
    Select * from testTable where width > 10.1 and width < 10.9
    order by abs (10.3 - width) asc
    LIMIT 1
```